# Getting Error In Flutter : RangeError (index) : Invalid value: Not in inclusive range

Tags: flutter, dart

I am flutter beginner and while practicing the Swipe to dismiss option I have completed the below mentioned code and after deleting few list items I am receiving the below error, I tried to solve the problem but couldn't,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items = new List<String>.generate(30, (i) => "Items ${i+1}");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Swipe To Dismiss"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,int index){
            return Dismissible(
                key: Key(items[index]),
              onDismissed: (direction){
                  items.removeAt(index);
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                      content: Text("ITEM IS SUCCESSFULLY REMOVED")));
              },
              background: Container(
                color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("${items[index]}"),
              ),

                );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

error while deleting list items and then scrolling down

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert stateless widget into statefull and use setState so that ListView gets rebuilded.

Below code is tested & working. [You can test it here.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3e095153b028d988c9342a51bd367cf7&null_safety=true)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  final List<String> items =
      new List<String>.generate(30, (i) => "Items ${i + 1}");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Swipe To Dismiss"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(items[index]),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                items.removeAt(index);
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                    content: Text("ITEM IS SUCCESSFULLY REMOVED")));
                setState((){});
              },
              background: Container(
                color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                    .withOpacity(1.0),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("${items[index]}"),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sucessfully fixed the issue . I converted MyHome from Stateless to StateFul Widget and added setState in `onDismissed` . Here is the changed code.

```
onDismissed: (direction){
                  setState(() {
                    items.removeAt(index);
                  });
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                      content: Text("ITEM IS SUCCESSFULLY REMOVED")));
              },
```